# Cabal shared sandboxes and sandbox-wide cabal.config

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm using cabal sandboxes feature to create an isolated build environment for my Haskell project, which has a plenty of packages. To do that I have a build script that first creates a sandbox by doing

```
cabal sandbox init
```

in a build directory and then calling

```
cabal sandbox add-source <path-to-project>
```

in that directory for every package of mine. In addition, to simplify the development process I launch

```
cabal sandbox init --sandbox <path-to-sandbox>
```

in every package directory I have. This allows me to do `cabal install` right from needed package directory and have all dependencies built and package installed to my sandbox.

Now I have a problem with a configuration file. I've created `cabal.config` next to the `cabal.sandbox.config` in a build directory, which has a couple of cabal flags (and extra-include-dirs, etc). It works (and settings seem to be applied) when I launch, for example, `cabal install HsOpenSSL` and my current directory is a build one (the one I've called `cabal sandbox init` and where `cabal.config` resides).

Now if I try launching `cabal install` from an HsOpenSSL project directory, `cabal.config` in my sandbox is ignored (despite the fact that `cabal sandbox init --sandbox <path-to-sandbox>` has been properly invoked previously and cabal gives a notice about installing to a sandbox).

And the question is if I could specify cabal options for all packages that are added to my sandbox in such a way that these options will apply even if I just launch `cabal configure/build/install` from a package directory?

I'm using Windows and cabal-install-1.22.0.0.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I eventually switched to Stack (http://haskellstack.org) and this solved a lot of headaches.